# Efficiently handling 52 toggle buttons in VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have made a button that will toggle an employee on or off for each week of a fiscal year.  I'll explain a bit more about my workflow afterwards, but my primary question is this:

Each button is named W1, W2, ..., W52.  Do I need to have an event script for EVERY button?

```
Private Sub W1_Click()
  updateActiveWeeks
End Sub
```

I guess I don't care if I need to have 52 mini-sub's, but it just seems rather inefficient to do things this way.  Plus if I need to do any updates, I need to do the update 52 times which will be a nightmare fast.

Bonus Points:
Ok more about the workflow.  How I'm making this form work is it runs 'updateActiveWeeks' anytime a button is pressed.  This sub loops through all the W1...W52 buttons to check their state and if it's true it will apply a specific code to a table on the employee's name.  Then "Form_Current" will then check this updated table and refresh the toggle buttons according to the coding to ensure that the right buttons are always pressed down (this way if you switch a record it will make sure that it shows the right states).  My secondary question is whether this is the optimal approach?  It 'works' but I'm curious if I'm refreshing things too much.

Comment: You could just have a separate update button that does all 52 weeks instead of updating for each button.  Or make each button only update itself instead of checking all the others. That's a waste since you know only the button selected was changed.

Comment: FYI, you can 'generate' code for events externally to Access, then paste into the code window for that module/form. Not that it solves this issue, but when faced with making 52 event handlers, I would write some vba code to create the code.

Comment: One thing I wonder is if there's no higher level event handler that checks if a button, any button, was pressed, and if so it will check the 52 toggle buttons to see their states.. i'm imagining something called "On Control Modified" at the Form Event level...

Comment: As for a button that refreshes it all-- indeed that would be the most simple way, but from a UI perspective I think the user would find that clunky.  I need something that watches the state of the toggle button and only triggers upon a change

Comment: I cringe at seeing 52 buttons, think checkboxes may be better?  Here's a half-baked idea.. a. create a small table with 52 boolean fields; b. create a small subform with 52 checkboxes and link to the table fields; when you change a value it will fire the 'Dirty' event for that subform so you could do something. If any of this makes sense, maybe more thought could persuade you otherwise!!

Comment: Wayne, I'm very open minded.  But wouldn't that still require 52 watchers?  Either for dirty tables or check boxes?

Comment: The 'Dirty' event will fire for any checkbox. You would need to figure which one it is (i.e loop thru the controls and compare the .Value property with the .OldValue property).  Then you would need to RESET the IsDirty flag in case they select another week (erh, I mean checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run the same event script for all 52 toggle buttons.

Add this code to the form:

```
    Private Function ToggleAny()
    updateActiveWeeks
    End Function
```

Now in Form Design:

- select all 52 toggle buttons
- press F4 for Properties
- for the On Click event, enter this text: `=ToggleAny()`

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is not the most efficient method. Why do you need to check every single button every time?

You can increase your efficiency by making `updateActiveWeeks` smarter.

```vb
Public Function updateActiveWeeks(btn As Control)
'Change recordset/apply code to table according to a state change in button "btn".
Forms(myForm).Controls(btn.Name).Enabled = Not Forms(myForm).Controls(btn.Name).Enabled
End Function
```

Now for each button sub, you just need to call this function and pass in the button's name.

```vb
Private Sub btn52_Click()
updateActiveWeeks(Me)
End Sub
```

You can add this same line of code to every button, so you should be able to simply select all of them and put in `updateActiveWeeks(this.Name)` and the above sub will be created automatically.

If you want more specific code, you'll have to provide more specific context. It certainly depends on how you're implementing this, but you may want to implement a <kbd>Start Over</kbd> button for your users with the following sub:

```vb
Sub StartOver()
Dim strTemp As String

For num = 1 to 52
strTemp = "btn" & num
Forms(yourForm).Controls(strTemp).Enabled = True
'Reset table value for the button with name "strTemp"
Next num

End Sub
```